# Kernel dies when trying to open Netcdf NARR file

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm trying to open NARR Netcdf files using netCDF4 to read its data, but when I try to open it, the kernel keeps dying. I'm using spyder with python 2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import netCDF4 as nc

f = nc.Dataset(r'C:\Users\...\uwnd.10m.1980.nc')

Kernel died, restarting
```

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what the issue is. Maybe running out of ram? how big is that netcdf? Is it just this file that you cant load or any of the NARR files. (ps i'm a weather guy so i deal with gribs and netcdf all the time, never seen this particular error)

Comment: The task manager doesn't show any excessive ram usage. The file is 540 mo and I've tried with other ones and it does the same thing